# Using other class initializers inside an initializer in Swift

Tags: swift

Can I use other initializers within my initializer?

```
class Car {
    var manufacturer:String?
    var speed:Int?

    init (manufacturer manf:String){
        manufacturer = manf
    }

    init(manufacturer manf:String, speed spd:Int){
        manufacturer = manf // How can I use the other initializer here?
        speed = spd

    }
}


var b = Car(manufacturer: "bmw")

var k = Car(manufacturer: "kia", speed: 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just need the `convenience` before my secondary `init` then I can use `self.init` to call the original `init`

```
class Car {
    var manufacturer:String?
    var speed:Int?

    init (manufacturer manf:String){
        manufacturer = manf
    }

    convenience init(manufacturer manf:String, speed spd:Int){
        self.init(manufacturer: manf)
        speed = spd

    }
}
```